# WPF DataGrid Combobox selectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, observablecollection

I have a DataGrid with a combobox assigned of Customer IDs, Each Customer ID may have many Account IDs which are assigned in their own combo box. All I want to do is, when a user selects a Customer ID from the combobox, the Account IDs are then updated with the specific CustomerID that was chosen.

I think I am nearly there with the code.

Here I have the itemsource of the customerId applied inside the combobox elementstyle. As you can see I have a property of SelectedItem when an Item is selected from the customer box.

```
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource"
                Value="{Binding DataContext.EntityCollection,
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                     AncestorType=Window}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Name"/>
                        <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding SelectedItem}"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
```

So inside the Combobox of the Account Id, I am not sure where to put the SelectedItem.AID code...

I have put it inside the SelectedValueBinding property in the first line, but it doesnt work. do I need to put SelectedItem inside the Itemsource porperty inside the EditingElementStyle tag?

```
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedValueBinding="{Binding SelectedItem.AID}"                SelectedValuePath="SID"  Header="SID" Width="70">
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource"
                Value="{Binding DataContext.EntityCollection, 
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                    AncestorType=Window}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="AID"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource"
                Value="{Binding DataContext.EntityCollection,
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                     AncestorType=Window}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="AID"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
```

However I could be way off, so any help I would be grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DataContext.EntityCollection,
```

I'm not entirely sure if that is possible, though I would not recommend using that this way.

Bind your `ViewModel` in the code behind to the `DataContext` of your `View`. Now you can bind the ItemsSource to any ObservableCollection Property in your ViewModel. That'd probably be your `EntityCollection`

Well, when using a `DataGridComboBoxColumn`, all you need to do, is to tell this column where the data is located by binding the target property.

If you'd have a list of `Customer` applied to your `DataGrid` and your property is named `ID`, your markup might be as follows:

```
SelectedValueBinding="{Binding ID, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Checking the `Mode` is highly required in order to transmit changes made to your property.

Now, to apply any changes to your other `ComboBox`, e.g. adding or creating items, you need to use another `ObservableCollection` and bind it to that second `Combobox`. If you done that, you can control the items of the second `ComboBox` when any changes are made to the first one.

Just a short sample how this might look:

```
private uint _ID;
public uint ID
{
    get { return _ID; }
    set
    {
        if (_ID == value) return;
        _ID = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange("ID");
        // Do something with your second ComboBox.
        // You could create another ObservableCollection and bind that to your second                   ComboBox and add some items representing the Account IDs
    }
}
```

Don't forget to notify your `View` when making changes.

If that wasn't the answer you are looking for, please be more specific. Your actual question was very hard to read, I only understood the first paragraph and explained, how you can archive what you want to do.

Comment: After a sleep i agree with you, what I want is something simpler, I will write another question, thanks